# Python: Insert data with for loop without timeout error

Tags: python, sql, clickhouse

I need to insert data by year batches but I'm getting

> Error on %Server% ping: timed out. Connection was closed,
> reconnecting.

And I don't know how long each insert will long.

I guess I should use async?

```
import pandas as pd
from clickhouse_driver import Client

client = Client(host, user=user, password=password, database = 'default')

dr = pd.date_range(start='1979-01-01', end='2029-01-31') # date ranges
for i in range(0,len(dr)):
    year  = dr[i].year
    query = f"insert into t2 select * from t1 where y = {year}"
    client.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tune `send_receive_timeout`

```
client = Client(host, user=user, password=password, database = 'default', send_receive_timeout = 1000)
```

https://github.com/mymarilyn/clickhouse-driver/issues/196